# Matplotlib title and axis label padding

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm just starting out experimenting with Matplotlib today. I've spent the last few hours trying to fix the positioning of the title and axis labels to no avail. I figured out to fix the spacing between the title and top of the chart and the axis labels and ticks using the padding parameter. I can't figure out how to make it so that the title is not crammed to top of the figure and the x/y axis labels aren't crammed to the left/bottom of the figure.

Below is an example that has nothing to do with my actual problem other than illustrating the formatting issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#create data
A = 5
f = 0.5
t = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y = A * np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

#create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(8*(16/9),8)
ax.plot(t,y)

#format plot
ax.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax.set_title('Need this title to move down without moving into subplot so that it is not crammed on top',pad=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Need this label to move to the right',labelpad=20)
ax.set_xlabel('Need this label to move up',labelpad=20)
```

[image: Example of formatting issue]

Any suggestions as to how to increase the margins between the outside of the title/labels and the edge of the figure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why use large pads if you don’t want a pad?  You can also use negative pads if the zero point is still too far for your taste

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#create data
A = 5
f = 0.5
t = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)
y = A * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)

#create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(8 * (16 / 9), 8)
ax.plot(t, y)

#format plot
ax.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.right.set_visible(False)

ax.set_title("Title", y=-0.1)

ax.set_xlabel("x-label")
ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top") 

ax.set_ylabel("y-label")
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
```

[image]

If you want to move x/y-ticks on top/to the right as well, then use the following commands:

```py
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
```

and then modify:

```py
ax.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.right.set_visible(False)
```

to

```py
ax.spines.bottom.set_visible(False)
ax.spines.left.set_visible(False)
```

[image]